# Ошибка при установке phonegap: npm ERR! not found: git

Tags: git, phonegap

**Предусловия:**

- JDK и Android SDK уже установлены,
- Node.js скачал и установил

**Воспроизведение ошибки:**

В консоли пишу `npm install -g phonegap`, появляется следующее сообщение:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
(c) Корпорация Майкрософт (Microsoft Corp.), 2009. Все права защищены.

C:\Windows\system32>npm install -g phonegap
npm WARN addRemoteGit Error: not found: git
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at F (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_mo
dules\which\which.js:72:28)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at E (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_mo
dules\which\which.js:75:29)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modul
es\which\which.js:83:16
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:95:15)
npm WARN addRemoteGit  git+https://github.com/imhotep/plugman.git#0.5.7 resettin
g remote C:\Users\pro-100\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\https-github-co
m-imhotep-plugman-git-20c32d58 because of error: { [Error: not found: git] code:
 'ENOGIT' }
npm WARN addRemoteGit Error: not found: git
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at F (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_mo
dules\which\which.js:72:28)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at E (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_mo
dules\which\which.js:75:29)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modul
es\which\which.js:83:16
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:95:15)
npm WARN addRemoteGit  git+https://github.com/filmaj/node-plist.git resetting re
mote C:\Users\pro-100\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\https-github-com-fi
lmaj-node-plist-git-653fe22e because of error: { [Error: not found: git] code: '
ENOGIT' }
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\pro-100\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-re
motes\_templates --mirror https://github.com/imhotep/plugman.git C:\Users\pro-10
0\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\https-github-com-imhotep-plugman-git-20
c32d58: undefined
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\pro-100\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-re
motes\_templates --mirror https://github.com/imhotep/plugman.git C:\Users\pro-10
0\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\https-github-com-imhotep-plugman-git-20
c32d58: undefined
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\pro-100\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-re
motes\_templates --mirror https://github.com/filmaj/node-plist.git C:\Users\pro-
100\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\https-github-com-filmaj-node-plist-gi
t-653fe22e: undefined
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\pro-100\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-re
motes\_templates --mirror https://github.com/filmaj/node-plist.git C:\Users\pro-
100\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\https-github-com-filmaj-node-plist-gi
t-653fe22e: undefined
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs
\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "phonegap"
npm ERR! node v0.12.6
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.2
npm ERR! code ENOGIT

npm ERR! not found: git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed using git.
npm ERR! This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Windows\system32\npm-debug.log

C:\Windows\system32>phonegap
"phonegap" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
```

Как мне это исправить?

**UPD**. Установил отдельно `npm` и `git` (может быть неправильно его установил там был выбор всякий). Но теперь вылазит это, вроде `phonegap` работает, нормальны ли эти ошибки?

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
(c) Корпорация Майкрософт (Microsoft Corp.), 2009. Все права защищены.

C:\Users\pro-100>npm install -g phonegap
npm WARN addRemoteGit Error: Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true config -
-get remote.origin.url
npm WARN addRemoteGit
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:751:12)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:1183:11)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Pipe.close (net.js:485:12)
npm WARN addRemoteGit  git+https://github.com/imhotep/plugman.git#0.5.7 resettin
g remote C:\Users\pro-100\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\https-github-co
m-imhotep-plugman-git-20c32d58 because of error: { [Error: Command failed: git -
c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origin.url
npm WARN addRemoteGit ]
npm WARN addRemoteGit   killed: false,
npm WARN addRemoteGit   code: 1,
npm WARN addRemoteGit   signal: null,
npm WARN addRemoteGit   cmd: 'git -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.ori
gin.url' }
npm WARN addRemoteGit Error: Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true config -
-get remote.origin.url
npm WARN addRemoteGit
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:751:12)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.
js:1087:5)
npm WARN addRemoteGit  git+https://github.com/filmaj/node-plist.git resetting re
mote C:\Users\pro-100\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\https-github-com-fi
lmaj-node-plist-git-653fe22e because of error: { [Error: Command failed: git -c
core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origin.url
npm WARN addRemoteGit ]
npm WARN addRemoteGit   killed: false,
npm WARN addRemoteGit   code: 1,
npm WARN addRemoteGit   signal: null,
npm WARN addRemoteGit   cmd: 'git -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.ori
gin.url' }
npm WARN engine ncallbacks@1.0.0: wanted: {"node":"~0.6.7"} (current: {"node":"0
.12.6","npm":"2.11.2"})
\
> cordova@2.7.4 install C:\Users\pro-100\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phoneg
ap\node_modules\cordova
> node bootstrap.js

SUCCESS: Minimum requirements for blackberry met.
BOOTSTRAPPING blackberry...
WARNING: Your system does not meet requirements to create wp7 projects. See erro
r output below.
"C:\Users\pro-100\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\cordova
\lib\cordova-wp7\bin\check_reqs" ?? ?????? ???????? ??? ?????
????????, ??????? ?????? ??? ???????? ????.

SKIPPING wp7 bootstrap.
WARNING: Your system does not meet requirements to create android projects. See
error output below.
The command `android` failed. Make sure you have the latest Android SDK installe
d, and the `android` command (inside the tools/ folder) added to your path. Outp
ut: "android" ?? ?????? ???????? ??? ?????
????????, ??????? ?????? ??? ???????? ????.

SKIPPING android bootstrap.
WARNING: Your system does not meet requirements to create ios projects. See erro
r output below.
Xcode is (probably) not installed, specifically the command `xcodebuild` is unav
ailable or erroring out. Output of `xcodebuild -version` is: "xcodebuild" ?? ???
??? ???????? ??? ?????
????????, ??????? ?????? ??? ???????? ????.

SKIPPING ios bootstrap.
WARNING: Your system does not meet requirements to create wp8 projects. See erro
r output below.
"C:\Users\pro-100\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\cordova
\lib\cordova-wp7\bin\check_reqs" ?? ?????? ???????? ??? ?????
????????, ??????? ?????? ??? ???????? ????.

SKIPPING wp8 bootstrap.
ERROR! Could not create a native blackberry project test fixture. See below for
error output.
Missing one of the following:
JDK: http://java.oracle.com
Apache ant: http://ant.apache.org

C:\Users\pro-100\AppData\Roaming\npm\phonegap -> C:\Users\pro-100\AppData\Roamin
g\npm\node_modules\phonegap\bin\phonegap.js
phonegap@0.9.4 C:\Users\pro-100\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap
├── colors@0.6.2
├── semver@1.1.0
├── qrcode-terminal@0.9.5
├── shelljs@0.0.9
├── optimist@0.3.7 (wordwrap@0.0.3)
├── node-static@0.6.9 (mime@1.3.4)
├── phonegap-build@0.8.0 (qrcode-terminal@0.8.0, phonegap-build-api@0.3.3)
├── prompt@0.2.14 (revalidator@0.1.8, pkginfo@0.3.0, read@1.0.6, winston@0.8.3,
utile@0.2.1)
└── cordova@2.7.4 (ncallbacks@1.0.0, open@0.0.3, shelljs@0.1.2, request@2.11.4,
elementtree@0.1.3, xcode@0.5.1, plist@0.4.0, prompt@0.2.7, express@3.0.6, ripple
-emulator@0.9.29, plugman@0.5.6)

C:\Users\pro-100>phonegap

Usage: node C:\Users\pro-100\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\bin\phone
gap.js [options] [commands]

Description:

  PhoneGap command-line tool.

Commands:

  create <path>        create a phonegap project
  build <platform>     build a specific platform
  install <platform>   install a specific platform
  run <platform>       build and install a specific platform
  local [command]      development on local system
  remote [command]     development in cloud with phonegap/build
  help [command]       output usage information
  version              output version number

Options:

  -v, --version        output version number
  -h, --help           output usage information

Platforms:

  android              target Android
  blackberry           target BlackBerry 10
  ios                  target iOS
  wp7                  target Windows Phone 7
  wp8                  target Windows Phone 8

Examples:

  $ node C:\Users\pro-100\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\bin\phonegap
.js help create
  $ node C:\Users\pro-100\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\bin\phonegap
.js help remote build
  $ node C:\Users\pro-100\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\bin\phonegap
.js create path/to/my-app
  $ node C:\Users\pro-100\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\bin\phonegap
.js remote build android
```

Comment: Вот хорошая инструкция по установке Git. Проверьте, что проделали все необходимые шаги. http://stackoverflow.com/a/323764/2790048

Answer (score 1):

```
npm ERR! not found: git
```

Говорит о том, что не установлен git и npm, соответственно, не может его использовать.

Comment: но ведь npm идет в комплекте с node.js?

Comment: @reddyk да, но git -- нет.